# Как в Qt можно изменить label формы из другого потока?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, winapi

Есть необходимость в том, чтобы несколько потоков могли выводить текст на форму одновременно. Как это можно сделать средствами Qt ?

```
// потоковая функция
DWORD WINAPI GeneralThreads::ThreadProcTest(LPVOID lpParametr){
    //while(1){}
    reinterpret_cast<Ui::MainWindow *>(lpParametr)->label->setText("thread_hell");
    return 0;
}

// ее вызов
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, &GeneralThreads::ThreadProcTest, ui, 0, nullptr);

// из класса MainWindow
public slots:
    void setLabel(char * name);
...
void MainWindow::setLabel(char * name){
ui->label->setText(name);
}
```

Вообще задача стоит такая: есть несколько потоков. необходимо обеспечить одновременный вывод информации из них. изначально в консольном приложении хотел создавать консоли для каждого. но в винде одна консоль - один процесс. (WinAPI) решил через формы и Qt. но здесь вроде из коробки тоже нельзя из левых потоков писать в GUI центрального.

Comment: Средствами Qt надо испускать сигнал с данными из потоков, которые ловить в слот в основном и в основном отрабатывать изменения. Как это совместить с WinAPI, не знаю, я бы конечно потоки через QThread/QtConcurrent реализовывал

Answer (score 4):

В Qt есть свои потоки, используйте их. Проще всего использовать сигналы и слоты, тогда фреймворк сам позаботится о безопасности.

Worker.h

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker(QObject *_parent = 0):
        QObject(_parent)
    {

    }

signals:
    void workProgress(const QString &_text);

public slots:
    void doWork()
    {
        for(int  i = 0 ; i < 100; i++)
        {
            QThread::msleep(100);
            emit workProgress(QString("%1/%2").arg(i + 1).arg(100));
        }
    }
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "worker.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_toolButton_clicked();
    void onThreadProgress(const QString &_text);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QThread m_thread;
    Worker m_worker;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    m_worker.moveToThread(&m_thread);

    connect(&m_thread, &QThread::started, &m_worker, &Worker::doWork);
    connect(&m_worker, &Worker::workProgress, this, &MainWindow::onThreadProgress);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_toolButton_clicked()
{
    m_thread.start();
}

void MainWindow::onThreadProgress(const QString &_text)
{
    ui->label->setText(_text);
}
```

Comment: Безопасно ли в такой ситуации передавать в сигнале строку по ссылке, а не по значению? Если я правильно понимаю, в этом случае может возникнуть race condition когда рабочий поток изменит строку до того, как эти изменения будут отражены в интерфейсе. В данном конкретном случае наверное это не критично, но в других случаях может испортить данные.

Comment: @Bearded Beaver если сигнал и слот находятся в разных потоках, фреймворк складывает передаваемые значения в буфер, и в MainWindow попадет константная ссылка на значение из буфера.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал этой детали. Получается, что это не особо и отличается от передачи по значению?

Comment: @Bearded Beaver в случае использования потоков - да, значение будет скопировано. Но если сигнал и слот в одном потоке, тогда значение будет передано по ссылке как и задумано. Это позволяет нам абстрагироваться от необходимости думать что копировать, а что передавать по ссылке.